# How can I show a specific django field in html?

Tags: python, html, django

So I want to do what the title says and I don't know how since I'm new at this.

```
<p>{{ form.description }}</p>
```

That's the way I show information from different models in a listing using

```
{% for form in forms %}
```

But I want to show the description of an specific object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your view that processes the form and the corresponding template.

Comment: You can list index like forms[0].description, or you should get only that item from the view

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Please explain if you need to display form(s) or field(s)? Some real world example would be helpful, example of forms/fields and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden_field.errors }}
        {{ hidden_field }}
    {% endfor %}

<table border="1">
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <tr>
    <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
    <td>
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field }}
      {{ field.help_text }}
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Look this article: [link][1]https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually django templates will be filled with the data rendered from the django views as dictionary and these will be callable in templates using django template tags "{{tag_name}}"

Here you will be rendering all the forms as a list inside the dictionary so you can show each form by looping it.

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {{form.description}}
{% endfor %}
```

Like this, you can show each form's data. Instead of this if you only want to show a specific form's data then the proper way is to render the view with the specific form's data and show data in template using the template tag {{form.description}}

Check the django documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/